# ant:taskdef Could not load definitions from resource org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

Here is my `build.gradle` , I had upgraded gradle 5.x to 6.9.2 and while executing `gradleW` build I am getting below error.

**[ant:taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties.** It could not be found.

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\9796te\Company\2021\December\27\01\hopper-api\build.gradle' line: 180

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
Problem: failed to create task or type iajc
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

And here is the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'com.adarshr.test-logger' version '1.6.0'
    id 'com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties' version '2.0.0'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.7'
    id "com.github.ManifestClasspath" version "0.1.0-RELEASE"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.bp.hopper.Application'

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

jar {
    enabled = true
    archiveBaseName = 'hopper-api'
    archiveVersion =  '0.1'
}

bootJar {
    classifier = 'application'
}

sourceSets {
    integration
}

configurations {
    aspects
    compile.extendsFrom aspects
}

springBoot  {
    buildInfo()
}

testlogger {
    theme 'mocha'
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "com.bp.WellHopper:hopper-api"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal() // For those who can't access internal BP repos
    //jcenter()
    maven { url 'http://dml-prime.bpweb.bp.com:8088/artifactory/bp-upstream-devops-lib-release-local' }
}

// Non-spring boot versions
ext.versions = [
    accesstokenvalidator: '2.1.4g',
    onbehalfof: '2.1.4f',
    clientcredentials: '2.1.4h',
    swagger: '2.9.2',
    applicationinsights: '2.6.0', // if you change this then change web.config and replace the updated jar in project root
    commonsio: '2.6',
    mssqljdbc: '7.2.2.jre8',
    xlxsstreamer: '1.2.0',
    guava: '27.1-jre',
    beanutils: '1.9.3',
    tika: '1.20',
    jacksondatatypejts: '2.4',
    azurestorage: '8.2.0',
    azurekeyvault: '1.2.4',
    azure: '1.34.0',
    hibernatesearch: '5.10.5.Final',
    reflections: '0.9.11',
    awaitility: '4.0.3',
    microsoftgraph: '1.2.0',
    dozer: '6.5.0',
    lombok: '1.18.12',
    hibernatetypes: '2.10.0',
    qpid: '0.55.0',
    javaobjectdiff: '0.95'
]

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {  details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'org.apache.logging.log4j') {
            details.useVersion '2.17.0'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$versions.lombok"

    aspects "org.springframework:spring-aspects"

    implementation "org.aspectj:aspectjrt"
    implementation "org.aspectj:aspectjtools"
    implementation "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver"

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jms'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-envers'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5'
    implementation ("org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial") {
        exclude group: 'org.postgresql', module: 'postgresql'
    }
    implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:$versions.hibernatesearch"
    implementation "com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-5:$versions.hibernatetypes"
    implementation "com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:$versions.azurestorage"
    implementation "com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph:$versions.microsoftgraph"
    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:$versions.lombok"
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    implementation "org.apache.tika:tika-core:$versions.tika"
    implementation "com.bedatadriven:jackson-datatype-jts:$versions.jacksondatatypejts"
    implementation "org.reflections:reflections:$versions.reflections"
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:$versions.guava"
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime'

    implementation "commons-io:commons-io:$versions.commonsio"
    implementation "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:$versions.mssqljdbc"
    implementation "com.monitorjbl:xlsx-streamer:$versions.xlxsstreamer"
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:$versions.swagger"
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:$versions.swagger"
    implementation "com.bp:access-token-validator:$versions.accesstokenvalidator"
    implementation "com.bp:access-token-on-behalf-of:$versions.onbehalfof"
    implementation "com.bp:access-token-client-credentials:$versions.clientcredentials"
    implementation "com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault:$versions.azurekeyvault"
    implementation "com.microsoft.azure:azure:$versions.azure"
    implementation "com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-web:$versions.applicationinsights"
    implementation "com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-logback:$versions.applicationinsights"
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2' // safe html
    implementation ("commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:$versions.beanutils") {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    implementation 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j'
    implementation "com.github.dozermapper:dozer-spring-boot-starter:$versions.dozer"
    implementation "org.apache.qpid:qpid-jms-client:$versions.qpid"
    implementation "de.danielbechler:java-object-diff:$versions.javaobjectdiff"

    testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$versions.lombok"
    testimplementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testimplementation 'com.vmlens:concurrent-junit:1.0.2'
    testimplementation 'io.github.benas:random-beans:3.7.0'
    testimplementation "com.flipkart.zjsonpatch:zjsonpatch:0.4.11"
    testRuntimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'

    integrationAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$versions.lombok"
    integrationimplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    integrationimplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    integrationimplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json'
    integrationimplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:$versions.lombok"
    integrationimplementation "io.rest-assured:rest-assured"
    integrationimplementation "com.monitorjbl:xlsx-streamer:$versions.xlxsstreamer"
    integrationimplementation "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:$versions.mssqljdbc"
    integrationimplementation "com.google.guava:guava:$versions.guava"
    integrationimplementation "commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:$versions.beanutils"
    integrationimplementation ('org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial') {
        exclude group: 'org.postgresql', module: 'postgresql'
    }
    integrationimplementation "com.bedatadriven:jackson-datatype-jts:$versions.jacksondatatypejts"
    integrationimplementation "org.awaitility:awaitility:$versions.awaitility"
    integrationimplementation "org.reflections:reflections:$versions.reflections"
    integrationimplementation "com.github.dozermapper:dozer-spring-boot-starter:$versions.dozer"
    integrationimplementation "com.flipkart.zjsonpatch:zjsonpatch:0.4.11"
}

compileJava {
    println 'Java Version: ' + JavaVersion.current()
    println 'Java Source Compatibility: ' + sourceCompatibility
    println 'Java Target Compatibility: ' + targetCompatibility
    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(resource: 'org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties', classpath: configurations.compile.asPath)
        ant.iajc(inpath: sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.asPath, classpath: configurations.compile.asPath, aspectPath: configurations.aspects.asPath, destDir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.asPath)
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integration.output
    classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
    minHeapSize = "512m"
    maxHeapSize = "2g"
    jvmArgs = [
            "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
            "-Duser.timezone=UTC"
    ]
}

bootRun {
    if (project.hasProperty('jvmArgs')) {
        jvmArgs = (project.jvmArgs.split("\\s+" as Closure) as List)
    } else {
        jvmArgs = [
                "-Dapp.security.enable=true",
                "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true",
                "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
                "-Duser.timezone=UTC"
        ]
    }
}

def createLocalDatabaseSql = "create database hopper\n" +
        "go\n" +
        "create login bp with password = 'bp', check_policy = off\n" +
        "go\n" +
        "use hopper\n" +
        "go\n" +
        "create user bp for login bp\n" +
        "go\n" +
        "sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'bp'\n" +
        "go\n" +
        "exit\n"

def dropLocalDatabaseSql = "drop database hopper\n" +
        "go\n" +
        "drop login bp\n" +
        "go\n" +
        "exit\n"

task createLocalDatabase(type: Exec) {
    standardInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(createLocalDatabaseSql.getBytes('UTF-8'))
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'sqlcmd'
}

task createLocalDatabaseDocker(type: Exec) {
    standardInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(createLocalDatabaseSql.getBytes('UTF-8'))
    commandLine 'sqlcmd', '-U', 'sa', '-P', 'Passw0rd'
}

task dropLocalDatabase(type: Exec) {
    standardInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(dropLocalDatabaseSql.getBytes('UTF-8'))
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'sqlcmd'
}

task dropLocalDatabaseDocker(type: Exec) {
    standardInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(dropLocalDatabaseSql.getBytes('UTF-8'))
    commandLine 'sqlcmd', '-U', 'sa', '-P', 'Passw0rd'
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
        plusConfigurations.add configurations.integrationCompile
        plusConfigurations.add configurations.integrationRuntime
    }
}
```

Comment: `testimplementation` should be camel-case `testImplementation`

Comment: Let me try thanks a lot for identification

Comment: on executing gradle build, I am getting below error now Above implementation issue is resolved.  ``` [ant:taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties. It could not be found.```